# How to insert textbox values which is present in gridview

Tags: asp.net

I have one gridview ,in that i'm using more than 5 textboxes in item template i want to insert the values present in textbox to table any body plz give your sugesstion

i tried the following method its showing error i write these lines in button click event

```
TextBox txtprod = (TextBox)sender;   
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)txtprod.Parent.Parent;  
int rowIndex = row.RowIndex;  
TextBox txtDetails
    =(TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtProd"); 
TextBox txtQuoQuantity=(TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("txtQuantity"); 
TextBox txtTax = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("txtTax");  
TextBox txtQuoRate = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("txtrate");  
TextBox txtQuoDis = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("txtDis"); 
TextBox txtQuoAmount = (TextBox)GridView2.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtAmt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Traverse the `Rows` collection of `GridView`.
2. Use `FindControl` method to get the reference of each TextBox in the `Cells` collection.
3. Prepare the `SQL - INSERT` statement to insert a row via `ADO.NET provider` or use `Entity framework.`

Comment: ya i tried findcontrol method its showing error for your reference here i paste my code